# Azure devops + helm chart = ##[warning]Capturing deployment metadata failed with error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'kind' of null

Tags: azure-devops, kubernetes-helm, pipeline

I use a helm chart to deploy on an AKS cluster via Azure Devops. Everything works fine but I see a warning at the end of the deployment step:

```
Starting: Deploy Helm chart to qa3 environment
==============================================================================
Task         : Package and deploy Helm charts
Description  : Deploy, configure, update a Kubernetes cluster in Azure Container Service by running helm commands
Version      : 0.201.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://aka.ms/azpipes-helm-tsg
==============================================================================
/usr/local/bin/helm upgrade --namespace qa3 --install --values /home/vsts/work/1/s/invitation/values.yaml --set deployment.image.tag=***,deployment.environment=qa3,cluster.name=dev,azure.region=westus2,azure.appInsightsKey=***,deployment.deployedBy='cd',application.publicJwtValidationCertPemBase64=***,application.endpointPath=invitational,application.sendGridTemplateId=***,application.twillioFromPhoneNumber=***,secret.AuthToken=***,secret.AccountSid=***,secret.SendGridApiKey=*** --wait --install --reuse-values q5id-app-invitation /home/vsts/work/1/s/invitation
Release "q5id-app-invitation" has been upgraded. Happy Helming!
NAME: q5id-app-invitation
LAST DEPLOYED: Wed Aug 10 14:53:19 2022
NAMESPACE: qa3
STATUS: deployed
REVISION: 3
TEST SUITE: None
/usr/local/bin/kubectl cluster-info
Kubernetes control plane is running at https://***:443
CoreDNS is running at https://***:443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy
Metrics-server is running at https://***:443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:metrics-server:/proxy

To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use 'kubectl cluster-info dump'.
##[warning]Capturing deployment metadata failed with error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'kind' of null
Finishing: Deploy Helm chart to qa3 environment
```

It looks like the template was successfully deployed, then the `kubectl cluster-info` was ran, then something else. I cannot understand what might cause this warning:

##[warning]Capturing deployment metadata failed with error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'kind' of null

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems I just had the same issue. The problem is that one of your helm templates is not loading properly.
Let's say your template is conditional and before the condition there is a comment

```
# enables PodDisruptionBudget
{{- if .Values.pdb }}{{ if .Values.pdb.enabled }}
apiVersion: policy/v1
kind: PodDisruptionBudget
...
{{- end }}{{ end }}
```

In some cases, it would work without warning when `if` is `true`. However, if it's a `false` your template is kinda "empty" and Azure should skip it. Unfortunately, it cannot, because there is a comment that Azure prints in the pipeline logs. Due to that the template is not skipped and Azure searches for `kind` of this template, but there is nothing, so this is why the warning appears. To solve it one needs to move the comment inside of the condition.